# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables not starting up in IBM i (AS400 / iseries)

Tags: mysql, ibm-midrange, privileges

I am trying to reset the grant privileges (I removed root privileges).

After I shut down the mysql daemon, I try to restart safe mode with: mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

I get this error & the default port is NOT listening after the attempted restart.:

```
 150402 13:40:27 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysqldata/TDIDEV2.T***C.COM.err'.              
 150402 13:40:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysqldata              
 150402 13:40:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysqldata/TDIDEV2.T***C.COM.pid ended
```

Err file:

```
 ñõðôðò@ñõzðñzñó@”¨¢˜“„m¢†…@â£™£‰•‡@”¨¢˜“„@„…”–•@¦‰£ˆ@„£‚¢…¢@†™–”@a¤¢™a“–ƒ“a”¨¢˜“„£%ñõðôðò@ñõzðñzñó@ºæ™•‰•‡»@â…££‰•‡@“–¦…™mƒ¢…m£‚“…m•”…¢~ò@‚…ƒ¤¢…@†‰“…@¢¨¢£…”@†–™@a¤¢™a“–ƒ“a”¨¢˜“„£a@‰¢@ƒ¢…@‰•¢…•¢‰£‰¥…%ñõðôðò@ñõzðñzñó@ºæ™•‰•‡»@Ö•…@ƒ•@–•“¨@¤¢…@£ˆ…@``¤¢…™@¢¦‰£ƒˆ@‰†@™¤••‰•‡@¢@™––£%%150402 15:01:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150402 15:01:13  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
150402 15:01:13  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: pthread_create returned 11
ñõðôðò@ñõzðñzñô@”¨¢˜“„m¢†…@”¨¢˜“„@†™–”@—‰„@†‰“…@a¤¢™a“–ƒ“a”¨¢˜“„£aãÄÉÄÅåòKãÉãÓÅÄÁãÁÉÕÃKÃÖÔK—‰„@…•„…„%
```

Comment: Please edit the question.  What does /usr/local/mysqldata/TDIDEV2.T***C.COM.err show?

Answer (score 0):

pthread_create 11 indicates an out of memory condition.  Did you also change `/usr/local/mysql/bin/my.cnf`?  8.0M seems very low for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, especially for IBM i.  Mine is set to 100M.